# Is there some .NET machine learning library that could, for example, suggest tags for a question?

Tags: c#, .net, machine-learning

Just to use it as an example, StackOverflow users already associated tags to questions for a lot of questions.

Is there a .NET machine learning library that could use this historic data to 'learn' how to associate tags to newly created questions and suggest them to the user?

Comment: That assumes the question will contain the relevant tags embedded in the text. For your question the algorithm could come up with ".Net" and "learn", but no C#.

Comment: @Noel: But is the question "correctly" tagged now?  I see what you mean, but to be honest the content of the question is only around .NET and machine learning - it could be written in F#, VB or managed C++ (if it was kept to just .NET)

Comment: @Noel Abrahams: where's that assumption? Who said the tags would be extracted from the text?

Comment: @arsmans, I don't know the point of your question. If you think it is going to be extracted from somewhere else then please enlighten us all by providing that answer.

Answer (score 10):

I made a machine learning library that might help: http://machine.codeplex.com. Its basic premise is that you can use simple lists of POCO objects and create models from them by annotating the classes. Hope this helps!

--- Update
I've since moved the project here: http://numl.net.

Answer (score 2):

There is a .NET library for popular statistical computing engine, R Project. The library is called [R.NET](http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/).

WEKA, the data mining tool for Java, mentions [several possibilities](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+with+the+Microsoft+.NET+Framework) to use the library with .NET. However, it's not ported or a wrapper but bridging the communication between .NET and Java.

Answer (score 1):

This looks similar to spam filtering, but with more buckets.

A widely used technique for spam filtering is [Bayesian filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_spam_filtering). A [Google search](http://www.google.com/webhp?q=bayesian+filter+c%23) will give you a lot of options, including the first hit on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/BayesianCS.aspx).

Comment: @Paul: When a question has no answer you shouldn't +1 for 'interesting article in links' as it removes the question from the unanswered questions list. I didn't check for it yet to see if answers the question.

Comment: @Ciwee, I don't thing that giving a +1 to a comment would remove the question from the unanswered question list. I think you're confusing that with accepting an answer

Comment: @Neowizard: The unanswered button on the top shows questions that hasn't been answered AND have no upvote, as you can see in the description on the top right hand corner of the page.

Comment: @Ciwee: In my opinion @Albin gave an interesting insight into how what you propose (which I think is a good idea) could be implemented.  If you would like to check the SO FAQ it clearly says that the community owns your question/answers and if you don't like that then SO is not the place for you - this extends to allowing people to vote up/down anything they please.

Comment: @Ciwee, what you're saying can't be right, because I browse question from the unanswered section all the time, and it contains many questions with up-voted not-accepted answers. I might show questions with accepted answered and no up-vote, but this is not the case bacause no answer has been accepted

Answer (score 1):

The subject of machine learning is a very complex field, and if you really want to create such an application you'll need some research done no matter what lib you're using.

In any case, I'd suggest using SVM (support vector machines). I've used it in python for this exact purpose, and it's incredible. You'll need to find a C# implementation though. The idea is to map features of text (like "words that end with .Net") to dimensions then use those features to create regions in the created space for tagging (anything in the sub-space X will be tagged as Y).

This is a really complex subject, and my explanation can only make it less clear, so I'll leave it up to you if you want, to read and use.

Here's something to get you started from [Wikipedia - Support Vector machine (SVM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine)

**Edit:** It seems that LibSVM (the library I worked with in python) is also available for C# from its [HomePage](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/). Good luck